# Can people in heaven see our world?

Tags: death, heaven

Do people who have died and are in heaven have the possibility to see our world? E.g. can my grandmother who passed away last year see me?

Comment: see #3 here http://www.dafyomi.co.il/berachos/points/br-ps-018.htm